# error C2248: 'Array<T>::Array' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Array<T>' when variable of certain type passed to std::async

Tags: c++

I'm not experienced with C++ and I'm trying to modify some C++ code (specifically, that of [paq8l](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/compression/#paq)). I'm trying to pass one of their data types as a parameter through `std::async`.

```c
int testTest(SmallStationaryContextMap &sscm)
{
    return 1;
}

int someOtherMethod()
{
    SmallStationaryContextMap sscm(0x20000);
    testTest(sscm); // fine
    auto future = std::async(testTest, sscm); // compiler error
}
```

I hope I'm just missing something simple, but this is giving me the error in the title. `error C2248: 'Array<T>::Array' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Array<T>'`

SmallStationaryContextMap:

```c
class SmallStationaryContextMap {
    Array<U16> t;
    int cxt;
    U16 *cp;
public:
    SmallStationaryContextMap(int m): t(m/2), cxt(0) {
        assert((m/2&m/2-1)==0); // power of 2?
        for (int i=0; i<t.size(); ++i)
        t[i]=32768;
        cp=&t[0];
    }
    void set(U32 cx) {
        cxt=cx*256&t.size()-256;
    }
    void mix(Mixer& m, int rate=7) {
        *cp += (y<<16)-*cp+(1<<rate-1) >> rate;
        cp=&t[cxt+c0];
        m.add(stretch(*cp>>4));
    }
};
```

And Array:

```c
template <class T, int ALIGN=0> class Array {
private:
    int n;     // user size
    int reserved;  // actual size
    char *ptr; // allocated memory, zeroed
    T* data;   // start of n elements of aligned data
    void create(int i);  // create with size i
public:
    explicit Array(int i=0) {create(i);}
    ~Array();
    T& operator[](int i) {
        return data[i];
    }
    const T& operator[](int i) const {
        return data[i];
    }
    int size() const {return n;}
    void resize(int i);  // change size to i
    void pop_back() {if (n>0) --n;}  // decrement size
    void push_back(const T& x);  // increment size, append x
private:
    Array(const Array&);  // no copy or assignment
    Array& operator=(const Array&);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `Array`s copy ctor is private: `Array(const Array&);  // no copy or assignment` and `std::async` is trying to make a copy of `sscm` which contains an `Array` as a member. Wrap it in a `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
auto future = std::async(testTest, std::ref(sscm));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your question:
https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/cannot-access-private-member-on-adding-to-tarray/418170/5

"You can’t declare an array of objects like that. They need to be object pointers."

```
Array<U16> t; => Array<U16*> t;
```